# What is the story behind Java Vulnerabilities?

Tags: java, vulnerabilities

I always appreciated the Java language. It is known as a very secure platform and many banks use it in their web applications.

I wanted to build a project for my school and I discussed the options with some developers. However, one of them said we should ignore Java ecause of vulnerabilities appreared recently in it.

For this reason I want to make sure, what is the story behind this and does that mean that Java today considered not much secure as it was previously?

Comment: The simplest way is to ask that developer what they meant. If they think Java isn't secure, they should back that claim with information.

Comment: No programming language is going to protect a company from the vulnerabilities created by software programmers.

Comment: Are you talking about Java the programming language, or Java / JVM / JRE the platform?

Comment: I hope that the other developer didn't propose PHP instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is what that developer is talking about.  See [here](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/1526/SUN-JRE.html?vendor_id=5) and [here](http://www.cvedetails.com/product/19117/Oracle-JRE.html?vendor_id=93) for a list of vulnerabilities in the run-time engine itself.  If you scroll to the bottom of [this page](http://www.cvedetails.com/product-list/product_type-/vendor_id-0/firstchar-J/page-2/products.html?sha=735df2f3815819f7abf172344df0bb60ea55d230&trc=434&order=1) and on to the next page you'll find more vulnerabilities that might be relevant, depending on what is in your software stack.

Why?

Well first you have to understand that Java is both a server and a client.  As a client, it tries to run in a carefully sandboxed way where mutually untrusted code can run in the same space.  This is a very hard problem, and it is used in enough "highly interesting targets" that a lot of effort has gone into breaking it.  The result is that most browsers will give you big security alerts before enabling Java.  It is simply too easy for an attacker to send you something which, when run by the JRE, will do Officially Bad Stuff that the security model said it shouldn't do.

People generally do not run untrusted code on a server, so most of that does not apply to you.

Of course there are still vulnerabilities that do apply.  But here we have a more complex question.  Is it better to have vulnerabilities that apply to you, but which you find out about?  Or to not know about vulnerabilities that apply to you?

Java is a high profile target, used in high profile applications.  So a lot of effort goes into finding bugs.  There are a lot of public bugs.  That go into automated attack tools.  That any kid can use, and any decent admin can defend against.  But a penetration tester will have a harder time finding a new one that nobody else has already found.

If you use a less known software stack, there are likely to be similar numbers of bugs, but less effort has been put into finding them.  That means that a random kid with an attack tool that knows a list of bugs is less likely to find something.  But any penetration tester examining your software stack will have a field day finding attacks that you have no way of defending against because you don't know about them.

If you're writing a high profile application (banking software, etc), you have to assume that competent attackers are a fact of life.  Therefore something like Java makes sense there.  If you're a small startup, Java might not make as much sense, but honestly for a startup, how vulnerable your language is is one of your least important problems.  Getting to be big enough that someone would want to attack you would be a Good Problem to have.

And, truth be told, anyone who wants to break into your site will first look around for the obvious SQL injections and the like.  Most of which will be your fault, and not the fault of your vendor.  Really, your language is not going to be your top source of security problems.  Your programming is.  Nor is it your second top source of security problems.  Your misconfiguration of your systems are.

In short, there are a lot of reasons to use or not use Java.  (I personally avoid the language.)  But security isn't a good reason to stay away, despite the large number of known security problems.

Comment: Hundreds of millions computers are connected to the internet, many of these browse the web. Hackers want to use thousands of computers for their shady purposes. For them it is cost-effective to target the lowest common denominaters: Java, Flash and Acrobat Reader are installed on almost any PC. Therefore the vendors Oracle and Adobe need to spend a lot of effort keeping up with the hackers, but nevertheless the general public with old versions is probably hacked already. If you consider Java programming as a profession, then Java is an excellent choice. There is a lot of demand for that skill

Answer (score 6):

Vulnerabilities exist in any large piece of software. Java is not alone in this regard.

Operating systems (Windows, osX, Android, Linux - pretty much all operating system) and many runtimes have had and will have vulnerabilities found.

What you got was the opinion of one person - this doesn't make it universally agreed on. Saying that a language is to be ignored because there were vulnerabilities found (in the language, its' implementation, common libraries and/or runtime) misses the point - every major language has been susceptible to some form of attach (C and buffer overruns, .NET has its own sets of issues etc... etc... etc...).

In short - so there were recent vulnerabilities. Presumeabely they have been patched or fixed in an update. Doesn't mean the language is no longer fit for use.